# Thread safety of VanillaChronicle

Tags: java, chronicle

I am using VanillaChronicle to write some messages to the disk.

```
public final class ConcurrentPersister{

    private final String location;
    private final Chronicle chronicle;
    private final ExcerptAppender writer;

    private final static int STRING_SIZE_OVERHEAD   = 1000;
    private final static String FILE_DATE_FORMAT    = "MM-dd-yyyy";
    private final static String NAME                = "ConcurrentPersister";
    private final static Logger LOGGER              = LoggerFactory.getLogger( NAME );



    public ConcurrentPersister( String location, VanillaChronicleConfig config ){
        this.chronicle      = new VanillaChronicle( location );
        this.writer         = chronicle.createAppender();
    }


   public final void appendMessage( final String message ){

        try{

            long length  =  STRING_SIZE_OVERHEAD + message.length();

            writer.startExcerpt( length );
            writer.append( message );
            writer.finish();

        }catch( Exception e ){
            LOGGER.warn("Failed to persist Message [{}]", message );
            LOGGER.warn("Exception: ", e );
        }

    }

}
```

Is the appendMessage(String message) method, as shown above, thread-safe if called from multiple threads?

I read somewhere that VanillaChronicle's append(String message) is thread-safe.
However, am I correct in thinking that the compound action of startExcerpt() + append() + finish() is NOT thread-safe?

Thanks.

Comment: Where does the writer object get initialised?

Comment: Sorry, in the constructor, fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VanillaChronicle has a ThreadLocal cache of appenders/tailers:

```
public VanillaAppender createAppender() throws IOException {
    WeakReference<VanillaAppender> ref = appenderCache.get();
    VanillaAppender appender = null;
    if (ref != null)
        appender = ref.get();
    if (appender == null) {
        appender = createAppender0();
        appenderCache.set(new WeakReference<VanillaAppender>(appender));
    }
    return appender;
}
```

If you do not have thousand short living threads you can use createAppender in your appendMessage method

```
public final void appendMessage( final String message ) {
    try {
        ExcerptAppender writer = chronicle.createAppender();
        writer.startExcerpt( STRING_SIZE_OVERHEAD + message.length() );
        writer.append( message );
        writer.finish();
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        LOGGER.warn("Failed to persist Message [{}]", message );
        LOGGER.warn("Exception: ", e );
    }
}
```

> I read somewhere that VanillaChronicle's `append(String message)` is thread-safe. However, am I correct in thinking that the compound action of `startExcerpt()` + `append()` + `finish()` is NOT thread-safe?

VanillaChronicle can be used by concurrent thread, even concurrent processes, provided each thread uses it's own appender.

Comment: +1 This allows you to write concurrently in different threads without needing to keep track of the Appenders yourself.  An `Appender` is designed to only be used by one thread at a time, so you need one for each thread to avoid locking.

Comment: Guys, shouldn't the createAppender() be synchronized to ensure that the process of creating and returning an appender executes as one atomic unit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronise the writer on those three method calls. `append( message );` might be thread safe but, as you say, the three separate method calls to writer could clash if multiple threads access the method through the same instance of ConcurrentPersister.

```
public final class ConcurrentPersister{

    private final String location;
    private final Chronicle chronicle;
    private final ExcerptAppender writer;

    private final static int STRING_SIZE_OVERHEAD   = 1000;
    private final static String FILE_DATE_FORMAT    = "MM-dd-yyyy";
    private final static String NAME                = "ConcurrentPersister";
    private final static Logger LOGGER              = LoggerFactory.getLogger( NAME );



    public ConcurrentPersister( String location, VanillaChronicleConfig config ){
        this.chronicle      = new VanillaChronicle( location );
        this.writer         = chronicle.createAppender();
    }


   public final void appendMessage( final String message ){

        try{

            long length  =  STRING_SIZE_OVERHEAD + message.length();

            synchronized(writer){
                writer.startExcerpt( length );
                writer.append( message );
                writer.finish();
               }

        }catch( Exception e ){
            LOGGER.warn("Failed to persist Message [{}]", message );
            LOGGER.warn("Exception: ", e );
        }

    }

}
```

Depending on what else you do with this class it might be easier to synchronise the whole method.

```
   public synchronized final void appendMessage( final String message ){
```

But this would synchronise on the instance of ConcurrentPersister, not the writer.